# Retrieving value of a select box populated by an ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here are the two select boxes. I am trying to get the value of C to pass on in a form. Select box C is populated from the ajax call below but I can't seem to get a useable value to pass on to the form. (In its simplest form I am looking for something like var A= 'select box C') then I can send 'A' in the form:

Many thanks in advance people x

```
<select name="list-select" id="list-select">
    <option value="">Please select..</option>
    <option value="Chemical">Chemical</option>
    <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
</select>

<select name="C" id="C"></select>
```

Here is the jquery bit:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        var list_target_id = 'C'; //first select list ID
        var list_select_id = 'list-select'; //second select list ID
        var initial_target_html = '<option value="">Please select a colour...</option>'; //Initial prompt for target select

        $('#' + list_target_id).html(initial_target_html); //Give the target select the prompt option

        $('#' + list_select_id).change(function (e) {
            //Grab the chosen value on first select list change
            var selectvalue = $(this).val();

            //Display 'loading' status in the target select list
            $('#' + list_target_id).html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');

            if (selectvalue == "") {
                //Display initial prompt in target select if blank value selected
                $('#' + list_target_id).html(initial_target_html);
            } else {
                //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.mypropertyviewing.com/Client_order_form_v1.1/selector.php?svalue=' + selectvalue,
                    success: function (output) {
                        $('#' + list_target_id).html(output);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you get if you console.log(selectvalue) after you assign it?

Comment: What does **output** give you?

Comment: Sorry Duenna I am new to this. I am still in the copy paste stage of learning and am learning well by looking at example code but it does mean I don't always understand answers unless made very simple and probably in context of the code that is already there. This means Im not sure what your answer is referring to.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
selectvalue=this.value //instead  of
selectvalue =$(this).val();
```

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is?

Comment: Thanks for answering Gaurav, however, I don't think that is correct. There are two select boxes: The first gives two static options which then gives a variable to ajax to populate the second select box (C) from a mysql database. This is all working fine and the 2nd select box (C) is being populated with data from database correctly. I just don't seem to be able to extract the option value of select box C to send to a form